# solve linear equation system based on matrix ("Matrix dimension must agree")

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I have a given matrix of size `NxN` (called `M`),a vector of `Nx1` (called `V`), and two scalars (called `a` and `b`). I want to solve the linear system of equations for alpha. The dimensions are given as MATLAB reports them using the function `size(-)`.

> (M + a * b * **1**) alpha == V

with **1** being a matrix of just 1s.

I figured the easiest way to do so would be

```
syms alpher; 
Mprep = (M + a * b * ones(length(M),length(M))); 
eqn = Mprep * alpher == V;
alpha = solve(eqn,alpher)
```

However, I get the error

> Error using ==
>   Matrix dimensions must agree

I am not sure whether this error is due to the fact that Matlab does not know the proper size of `alpher` or if I am just plain wrong in my approach. The error occurs in the second last line according to matlab.

What is the best way to solve this in MATLAB?

Comment: as in this case `M = N` based on M being symmetric and thus `ones(length(M),length(M))` having the same dimensions as M itself. Additionally the error occurs in the second last line so any presumed error in a previous line is rather unlikely. (this was a response to a now deleted comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve for an array of symbolic variables, you actually have to create an *array* of symbolic variables. Currently MATLAB sees `alpher` as a *scalar* and this obviously has dimension issues when performing matrix multiplication since an `N x N` matrix times a scalar is not equal to an `N x 1` array.

Rather than using the symbolic toolbox at all, I would recommend simply using MATLAB's built-in ability to solve a linear system of equations using the `\` operator ([`mldivide`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html))

```
alpha = Mprep \ V;
```

As a side note, please refrain from using `length` as the result is ambiguous as it simply returns the *first* non-singleton dimension. If you want the size of the `ones` to be equal to `M` just use `ones(size(M))`, alternately if you specifically want the number of rows or columns in `M` use the second input to `size` to specify the dimension that you'd like to query: `nRows = size(M, 1)` or `nCols = size(M, 2)`